# Is there a way to get reference to a viewController in storyboard without instantiating it again?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a `ViewController` menu that contains a tableView with selected items. I keep it inside a Container outside my navigation controller. I need to create that `ViewController` only once and present it from time to time across my app. I know I can save the ViewController inside a singleton class in order to use it but I was wondering, is there a better way doing that?

Answer (score 0):

The only methods in `<UIKit/UIStoryboard.h>` are

```
+ (UIStoryboard *)storyboardWithName:(NSString *)name bundle:(NSBundle *)storyboardBundleOrNil;

- (id)instantiateInitialViewController;
- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
```

so I don't believe you be able to get a view controller from the storyboard without instantiating a new one.

You could make a singleton class, or keep a reference around in your AppDelegate, whichever suits your needs best.